# MySQL - Passing Dynamic Column Names in Stored Procedures Using Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been pulling my hair out over this for the last 12 hours. I am trying to create a stored procedure to display the results of a search from a PHP page. There are a couple column names that are dynamic and are passed in by the php page. I thought i could use a prepared statement to get around this, but it doesn't seem to be working. When i run the SP below in phpMyAdmin, i get zero rows returned.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AllLoads7`( 
        IN p_search_field VARCHAR(25), 
        IN p_search_for VARCHAR(250), 
        IN p_load_status INT, 
        IN p_date_field VARCHAR(25), 
        IN p_startDate DATETIME, 
        IN p_endDate DATETIME, 
        IN p_employeeID INT,
        IN p_OrderBy VARCHAR(25)
    )
begin
SET @GetLoads = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM loads_contacts WHERE ",p_search_field," LIKE '%",p_search_for,"%' AND status LIKE '%",p_load_status,"%' AND ",p_date_field," BETWEEN '",p_startDate,"' AND '",p_endDate,"' AND company_id IN(SELECT company_id FROM employees_companies WHERE employee_id = ",p_employeeID,") ORDER BY ",p_OrderBy);
PREPARE stmt FROM @GetLoads;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
end
```

Here is how phpMyAdmin is calling it

```
SET @p0='pronumber'; 
SET @p1='1'; 
SET @p2='1'; 
SET @p3='dateCreated'; 
SET @p4='2010-01-01'; 
SET @p5='2014-01-01'; 
SET @p6='2'; 
SET @p7='status'; 

CALL `AllLoads7`(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7);
```

if I add "SELECT @GetLoads;" to the SP, i get the following query. If i run that query against my database, i get the expected rows returned. This tells me that the SQL is being generated correctly, it just seems that i'm not doing something quite right to execute the prepared statement

```
@GetLoads
SELECT * FROM loads_contacts WHERE pronumber LIKE '%1%' AND status LIKE '%1%' AND dateCreated BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND company_id IN(SELECT company_id FROM employees_companies WHERE employee_id = 2) ORDER BY status
```

Comment: Aren't you calling your procedure `AllLoads` and trying to access it as `AllLoads7`?

Comment: Troubleshooting PHP / MySql can be tricky when using stored procs.

As a step, you could print out the call in your PHP, and then try executing exactly that.

I'm assuming that you have other stored procedures working properly?

Comment: Also, your procedure is AllLoads, and the call is requesting AllLoads7.

Comment: the AllLoads7 was just a typo on my part when i creating this question. The sp and the call are both using AllLoads7. i just corrected it above.

I haven't tried to call this from PHP yet. I have just been troubleshooting it in phpMyAdmin just to make sure i have the proc setup correctly. Once i get the proc to return the rows in phpMyAdmin, i was going to move on and write the PHP code to call teh proc. I was just trying to take one step at a time

Comment: I do have other stored procedures working, but this is the first time i have tried to use a prepared statement. I don't normally make the table names or column names dynamic, but after some research, this seems to be what i need to do to make the column names dynamic